# Why img tag only display half of the image?

Tags: html, image

Could anybody explain why the following code would display only half image?

```
<img src="http://amragl.com/images/entrada.gif" alt="la tabla de gongora" style="width:400px; height:241px;overflow:visible"/>
```

I really can find an answer or a fix for this silly problem.

I am using Chrome Ver 25.0.1364.97 m and IE10.

see example below.

Thanks in advance.

**Live View**
http://jsbin.com/ipixod/1/
**Code Edit**
http://jsbin.com/ipixod/1/edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image file is corrupted, as you can see here: http://amragl.com/images/entrada.gif

Comment: Thanks!! I though it was styling issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with img tag. Actually, you image is corrupted. Try opening the image directly in browser.

Answer (score 0):

Your original image is at http://amragl.com/images/entrada.gif

You have specified the fixed dimensions `style="width:400px; height:241px;overflow:visible"` to the image. So it is appearing as per the dimensions.

make changes to the dimensions to set it accordingly.

The problem is with image.